# How can text be placed on upper left corner of Apple Watch screen

Tags: apple-watch

I'm using Xcode to develop an Apple Watch app. I would like to place some text on the very upper left portion of the screen, adjacent to where the time is listed.

When I drag a label up to the portion of the screen it auto-aligns down.

I see that most Apple Watch apps have a page title or the app name on the very upper left region of the screen so there must be some way to put text there.

How can text be placed on the very upper left corner of the Xcode screen? So that the text is on the same y axis level as the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the title of an interface controller, which you can set with [setTitle(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619570-settitle).

Comment: Yep, you're right. The title can also be set from the interface.storyboard. It is necessary to build the app and run the code for the title to show up, it won't show up in the storyboard. Thanks for your help.